# OpenGL glfwCreateWindow() vs glViewport()

Tags: c++, opengl

im learning OpenGL programming in C++ using GLFW and GLAD by refering [triangle from LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) and i have a quention from this example program , also im not so pro at both c++ and Opengl kindly help.

here comes the question :

in the program i used `glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);` and `glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);` at line 43 and 184 respectively. so the program draws/renders a triangle which maybe due to glViewport() function . and the triangle gets displayed to the screen maybe because of the glfwCreateWindow() fuction .

QUESTION = if the dimensions of the opengl viewport differs from that of the dimensions of the GLFW window then how would the program render the triangle? say if the dimensions of the glViewport is set to half the dimensions of the GLFW window then will the triangle be displayed in half of the GLFW window? sorry if my question does not make sense , i have an image to help you understand what im trying to ask/know..

`glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"text",NULL,NULL);` and `glViewport(0,0,800,600);` this works but

`glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"text",NULL,NULL);` and `glViewport(0,0,400,300);` will this work like this in the image ?

[image: Openglquestion]

sould i expect this?

[image: openglQuestionPic]

Answer (score 1):

[`glViewport`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) specifies the transformation from NDC (normalized device coordinates) to window coordinates. It defines the area of the framebuffer in which the scene is drawn. Note, however, that the framebuffer size may differ from the window size (e.g. if the screen is scaled). So if you want to draw the scene in the lower left quad of the window, you must use half the framebuffer size:

```cpp
int fbSizeX, fbSizeY;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &fbSizeX, &fbSizeY);
glViewport(0, 0, fbSizeX / 2, fbSizeY / 2);
```